# Node.js scraiping using Node.io

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

I am trying Node.js to get all the titles of this page: https://www.odesk.com/jobs/braintree

I try this:

```
var nodeio = require('node.io');
var methods = {
    input: false,
    run: function() {
        this.getHtml('https://www.odesk.com/jobs/braintree/', function(err, $) {

            //Handle any request / parsing errors
            if (err) this.exit(err);

            var titles = [], scores = [], output = [];

            //Select all titles on the page
            $('.content').each(function(a) {
                titles.push(a.text); 
            });
this.emit(output);
        });
    }
}

exports.job = new nodeio.Job({timeout:10}, methods);
```

But I'm getting nothing as a result. What is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't accurately traversing the markup. And your use of `each` is incorrect. Try this:

```
$('a', '.content h3').each(function(index, a) {console.log($(a).text())});
```